# convert byte array to short array

Tags: arrays, type-conversion

I want to convert a `byte` array to a `short` array. Please give me a solution to find it.

Comment: The solution is to learn programming and write the code. Not to ask off-topic questions here. We are not a coding service.

Comment: Also, this question does not have anything to do with Android specifically.

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert byte array to shorts array like this using ByteBuffer

```
byte[] bytes = {};
short[] shorts = new short[bytes.length/2]; 
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
```